# how to align text element to right-bottom in CSS grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

I want to have .form col-1 inside text to be at right botom:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, [col-start] 1fr);
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.form-col-1 {
  grid-column: col-start / span 5;

}
.form-col-2 {
  grid-column: col-start 6 / span 7 ;
}
```

Comment: without the `html` it's difficult to help you, but have you tried this in css: `position:absolute; right:0px; bottom:0px;` ?

Comment: you can use js+HTML+CSS snippet to help us to help you.

Comment: Please add a [mcve] - you're missing the HTML entirely.

Answer (score 14):

You could use Flexbox on first column and set `justify-content` and `align-items` to `flex-end`.

```css
.wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: 7fr 5fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 20px;
}
.form-col-1 {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: flex-end;

}
.form-col-2 {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="form-col-1">Col 1</div>
  <div class="form-col-2">Col 2</div>
  <div class="form-col-1">Col 3</div>
  <div class="form-col-2">Col 4</div>
</div>
```